# Attribute for accessing custom properties in Forms Designer

Tags: c#, attributes, windows-forms-designer

I have a control that has a list of Rods. The Rods have a few public properties:

```
    public class Rod
    {
        float Angle { get; set; }
        Color MainColour { get; set; }
        int Length { get; set; }
        int Width { get; set; }
        //other private code here you need not be concerned with ;)
    }
```

In the control that hosts the Rods, the list is declared as:

```
public List<Rod> Rods { get; set; }
```

I would like to be able to select a RodsHost control and click on the "Rods" property page, and edit the Rods on that control through the Forms Designer GUI. Currently, I can add Rods to the list, but not edit the Rod's properties (Angle, MainColour, etc...). I tried applying the attribute `[DesignTimeVisible(true)]` to the Rods class, that didn't seem to work. I thought maybe I should use the Designer attribute, but I'm not sure which Designer class I need here. Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I needed to decorate the list as:

`[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`

as well as add a constructor to set some appropriate default values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you out or not but what I did was create a **userControl** and within it created the properties as get set. The properties then showed up automatically in the Properties pane in the visual IDE.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't seem to have worked. The regular properties inherited from Control appear in the Properties pane when I edit the list, but the custom ones I added didn't show up.